# a failure occured while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$actionFacade see the console for details

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

i got several error when i build unity project to apk

> Configure project :launcher
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> aapt2.exe W 11-19 13:53:53 11828 12404 LoadedArsc.cpp:657] Unknown chunk type '200'.

> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
> 45 actionable tasks: 13 executed, 32 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

is there any solution?
i've seen some similar question but no solution

solution for my project

Comment: I didn't see any error in your question, please find it in the console or from the editor log.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).